# Is there a color scheme for Tweetdeck fitting the Radiance theme?

Tags: themes, adobe-air

Tweetdeck is nice, but it doesn't fit to the look of the Radiance theme …

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be, but if you can edit the colour scheme of the current theme, you can quickly put your own together. You can find the radiance colours by going into **System** -> **Preferences** -> **Appearance** and selecting the Radiance theme (if you're not already running it, and press customize. Select the colours tab from the menu that appears then select the colour you want and a picker will appear with the HEX value of the colour, which you can copy into the appropriate field in Tweetdeck.